# Re-evaluating controller functions from within ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have the following angular code:

```
<tr ng-repeat="vm in ...">
    <span ng-if="myLookupFunc(vm)"> {{myLookupFunc(vm)).label}}, {{myLookupFunc(vm).uuid}}
    <span ng-if="!myLookupFunc(vm)">-</span>
</tr>
```

As you can see myLookupFunc is called 4 times for a single item.
How can this be optimized so that it is called only once for a given 'vm' instance?
I did try to use ng-init at 'tr' level but it doesn't re-evalute after properties of 'vm' change -- and it is expected, according to the documentation ng-init should not be used for such cases.

So what is a proper way in angularjs to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code for better optimization.

```
<tr ng-repeat="vm in ..." ng-init="lookupData=myLookupFunc(vm)">
    <span ng-if="lookupData"> {{lookupData.label}}, {{lookupData.uuid}}
    <span ng-if="!lookupData">-</span>
</tr>
```

Comment: As I mentioned above I did try that, but the function will only be called once on the initial rendering and will be evaluated only when 'vm' itself changes, but the lookup function can change its results based on other external conditions

Answer (score 0):

`ng-init` will run once on the start of the `ng-repeat`. That's why it doesn't change for you.

You have to use the controller to fetch the variable data, but you **can** improve it.

One way is to do this on your controller:

```
function lookup(vm, firstRun) {

    if (firstRun) {
       $scope.lookupVar = myLookupFunc(vm);
    }
    else {
       return $scope.lookupVar;
    }
}
```

and then you can keep your html code almost the same:

```
<tr ng-repeat="vm in ...">
    <span ng-if="lookup(vm, true)"> {{lookup(vm)).label}}, {{lookup(vm).uuid}}
    <span ng-if="!lookup(vm)">-</span>
</tr>
```

**A better solution** would be to just keep one span in the HTML and then do:

```
<tr ng-repeat="vm in ...">
    <span>{{getVmText(vm)}}</span>
</tr>
```

And define a function `getVmText` on the controller that checks for VM value and returns the text. I believe this is the preferable way.

Comment: The second case would work in simple cases, In my case the actual content is more compicated and includes calling custom directives etc (not shown here). So I think I will try your first approach. Looks hackish, but there might not be a better way. If only there is something like ng-assign, which would behave like ng-init but would evaluate each time. Not sure, maybe if writing such directive would be simple

Answer (score 0):

Use a data model and update it whenever necessary (even when "external events" occur). This way you don't have to bother with "re-evaluating controller functions", it's just pure angular data binding.

Example:

```
$scope.vms = ["id1", "id2", "id3"];

// this var will hold your data model (it could also be on the $scope, but for 
// demo let's leave it like this) 
var data = {
  "id1": {
    uuid: "123-123",
    label: "label 1"
  },
  "id2": {
    uuid: "456-456",
    label: "label 2"
  },
  "id3": {
    uuid: "abc-abc",
    label: "label 3"
  }
};

$scope.myLookupFunc = function(id) {
  return data[id];
};
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="vm in vms" ng-init="lookupData=myLookupFunc(vm)">
  <span ng-if="lookupData"> {{lookupData.label}}, {{lookupData.uuid}}</span>
  <span ng-if="!lookupData">-</span>
</div>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/a6JtiyrPwQQPn6ooaxpJ?p=preview)

Comment: So in your example there is external async process that is updating the data. However, how to match the original case, where the evaluation has to happen each time then html is rendered?

Comment: @Ivan You don't want to run the `myLookupFunc(vm)` every time the HTML is rendered, is that it? If that's the case then we need to know what your `myLookupFunc` is doing in order to optimize it.

Comment: Yes that is the case. Lookup function has to be done in a efficient manner. In my case it is in-memory lookup combining two arrays

Comment: For cases where the function is expensive, I agree your approach of storing the data is good, but I consider it an further optimization technique (at the expense of simplicity), but for simple functions I think the approach above is valid

Answer (score 0):

OK, after considering the suggestions above, I found what I think is the easiest solution.

We just need to run

```
{{lookupData = myLookupFunc(vm)}}
```

and after that we can reference 'lookupData' variable. If we just run the code above inline, it will also evaluate and show the result (as JSON stringified text) inline, which is not what we want. So I ended up creating a dedicated directive which is a noop directive:

```
app.directive("ngAssign", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A'
    };
});
```

Then one can just say:

```
<tr ng-repeat="vm in ..." ng-assign={{lookupData = myLookupFunc(vm)}}>
    <span ng-if="lookupData"> {{lookupData.label}}, {{lookupData.uuid}}
    <span ng-if="!lookupData">-</span>
</tr>
```

Full plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/34DwCGR7Po8zg2mnCAtB?p=preview

Comment: That way you will be evaluating the `myLookupFunc(vm)` every time the UI is rendered, which is a bad practice. It will slow down your app. Don't go that way...

Comment: But that is the goal, to evaluate it once every time UI is rendered , instead of 4 times as in original example. Of course the lookup function has to be efficient

Comment: Also the function is not allowed to return an array of non-primitive objects. If it does it, one would encounter a well known '10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!' issue.